# XML parsing function is taking minutes to try to parse a document and then throwing an exception, can it be sped up?

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, xerces, xalan

I am unfortunately having to pass Xalan an XML document to try to parse that I can not guarantee is an XML document. In one case, the user has entered in a HTML document instead. This causes XalanDefaultParsedSource::create(...) to spend a minute in some cases before finally throwing an exception. How can I reduce the time that it is taking to attempt to parse and speed up the discovery of the fact that it's not a valid HTML document?

Answer (score 0):

The most likely reason it is taking so long is that it is fetching things (such as a DTD) from the web; most likely it is requesting a W3C DTD such as the XHTML DTD. W3C is deliberately responding to such requests very slowly because their servers cannot handle the load. The answer is to use an entity resolver that intercepts requests for these DTDs.

Comment: You know I was thinking this was a possibility and I followed their convoluted codepath through 50 function calls and still couldn't see it doing this. I can run a network trace to see if that's indeed happening.